# Electron require modules: due to diffrent working directory while runtime intellisense is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, intellisense

Im writing an electron-app with vs-code. First I had some problems with requiring local files as modules, but i managed to fix them. The only problem now ist that i've lost intellisens for these local modules.

Project structure:

```
+---app
|   |   config.json
|   |   index.html
|   |
|   +---css
|   |       style.css
|   |
|   +---js
|           config.js
|           render.js
|
|   main.js
|   package.json
|   README.md
```

My goal: use the methods from `config.js` in `render.js`.

I realize by now why vs-code behaves like it does but I dont see any solution: when the application is running the current working direcotry(`__dirname`) is `./app` so i have to require the config.js-file over `require(./js/config)`. The downside ist i lose complete intellisense for this module.

When im developing and have the `render.js` file open the current directory from vs-code's point of view is `./app/js`, so the relativ path to my module is `./config.js`. Now i would have intellisense again but the application is not working anymore:
  `require(./config)` results in `error: cannot find module`

Is there any way that the application runs and i get intellisense in vs-code? I am grateful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.. I was referencing the `render.js` in the index.html file.  If I load it with `require(./app/js/render)` in the `app.js` file everything works fine, including intellisens.

Answer (score 1):

Like you've discovered; the problem is vscode and the app not using the same starting point.
This is what I did to get it working:

Hierarchy:

```
+---assets
|   |
|   +---js
|       |    index.js
|       |    other.js
|   
|   main.js
|   index.html
|   renderer.js
```

In **index.html** I load renderer.js like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require("./renderer");
</script>
```

That way both the app and vscode uses the root folder as a starting point.
And in **renderer.js** this is all I have:

```
require('./assets/js/index');
```

That allows me to require other.js in index.js with working intellisense.
**index.js**:

```
const Other= require('./other').default;
...
```

And lastly **other.js**:

```
class Other{
    ...
}
module.exports.default = Other;
```